# Sorting by number of repetitions

Tags: perl, shell, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
192.168.2.2 150.25.45.7 8080
192.168.12.25 178.25.45.7 50
192.168.2.2 142.55.45.18 369
192.168.489.2 122.25.35.7 8080
192.168.489.2 90.254.45.7 80
192.168.2.2 142.55.45.18 457
```

I made up all the numbers.

I need to sort all these files according to the number of repetitions of the first ip. So the output would ideally look like this:

```
192.168.2.2 8080 369 457 3
192.168.489.2 8080 80 2
192.168.12.25 50 1
```

So: first ip, all the ports that were in lines with that first ip, and the number of repetitions.

I've been trying to play with the sort command and awk but I don't want to do extra work and maybe be missing out on some other straightforward solution.

Any idea? Thanks :)

Comment: It's called frequency or histogram

Comment: I added a line on that. I'm just wondering if I'm missing on some straightforward solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Perlish answer would look something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %data;

# Store IP address and port number
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($ip, undef, $port) = split;
  push @{$data{$ip}}, $port;
}

# Sort (in reverse) by length of list of ports
for (sort { @{$data{$b}} <=> @{$data{$a}} } keys %data) {
  say "$_ @{$data{$_}} ", scalar @{$data{$_}};
}

__DATA__
192.168.2.2 150.25.45.7 8080
192.168.12.25 178.25.45.7 50
192.168.2.2 142.55.45.18 369
192.168.489.2 122.25.35.7 8080
192.168.489.2 90.254.45.7 80
192.168.2.2 142.55.45.18 457
```

Output:

```
192.168.2.2 8080 369 457 3
192.168.489.2 8080 80 2
192.168.12.25 50 1
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Can you explain what the <=> part does? I'm curious. Thanks!

Comment: Read the documentation for sort (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) and the section in perlop on equality operators (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators).

Answer (score 2):

A Perl way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %repeat;
while(<DATA>) {
    if (/^(\d+(?:.\d+){3})\s\S+\s(\d+)$/) {
        push @{$repeat{$1}}, $2;
    }
}
foreach (sort {@{$repeat{$b}}<=>@{$repeat{$a}}} keys %repeat) {
    my $num = @{$repeat{$_}};
    print "$_ @{$repeat{$_}} $num\n";
}

__DATA__
192.168.2.2 150.25.45.7 8080
192.168.12.25 178.25.45.7 50
192.168.2.2 142.55.45.18 369
192.168.489.2 122.25.35.7 8080
192.168.489.2 90.254.45.7 80
192.168.2.2 142.55.45.18 457
```

**output:**

```
192.168.2.2 8080 369 457 3
192.168.489.2 8080 80 2
192.168.12.25 50 1
```

Comment: I think you missed the requirement to sort the output by the number of occurrences of each source IP address.

Comment: @davorg: Yes I did. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %ips;
push @{$ips{$_->[0]}}, $_->[1]+0 for map{[split/ \S+ /]}<DATA>;

for (sort {@{$ips{$b}} <=> @{$ips{$a}}} keys %ips) {
    printf("%s %s %d\n", $_, join(" ", @{$ips{$_}}), 0+@{$ips{$_}});
}

__DATA__
192.168.2.2 150.25.45.7 8080
192.168.12.25 178.25.45.7 50
192.168.2.2 142.55.45.18 369
192.168.489.2 122.25.35.7 8080
192.168.489.2 90.254.45.7 80
192.168.2.2 142.55.45.18 457
```

Output:

```
192.168.2.2 8080 369 457 3
192.168.489.2 8080 80 2
192.168.12.25 50 1
```

Answer (score 0):

this line should do the job for you:

```
awk '{a[$1]++;b[$1]=b[$1]" "$3}END{for(x in a)print a[x]"\t"x,b[x],a[x]}' input |
sort -nr|cut -f2-
```

**test** with your example

```
kent$  cat tt
192.168.2.2 150.25.45.7 8080
192.168.12.25 178.25.45.7 50
192.168.2.2 142.55.45.18 369
192.168.489.2 122.25.35.7 8080
192.168.489.2 90.254.45.7 80
192.168.2.2 142.55.45.18 457

kent$  awk '{a[$1]++;b[$1]=b[$1]" "$3}END{for(x in a)print a[x]"\t"x,b[x],a[x]}' tt |
sort -nr|cut -f2-
192.168.2.2  8080 369 457 3
192.168.489.2  8080 80 2
192.168.12.25  50 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pipeline relying mainly on awk and sort:

```
sort -k1 -k3n \
| awk -F' ' '
    NR==1 { 
      printf("%s ", $1); 
      current = $1 
    } 
    $1 != current { 
      printf(":%d\n%s ", count, $1); 
      current = $1; 
      count = 0 
    } 
    { printf("%d ", $3); count++ } 
    END { printf(":%d\n", count) }' \
| sort -t':' -k2nr \
| tr -d':'
```

Answer (score 0):

*GNU awk* 4:

```
awk 'END {
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
  for (e in ic)
    print e, ip[e], ic[e] 
  }
{
  ip[$1] = $1 in ip ? ip[$1] OFS $NF : $NF
  ic[$1]++
  }' infile
```